# How to refile to the top of another heading?

Tags: org-mode, org-refile

When refile a heading in org mode, I would like to refile it to the top of the target heading so that the new subheading is the first entry.

For my use case, I use `org-capture` for meeting notes, and when I'm done, I will file the meeting notes to my `* MEETINGS` heading. I order all the meeting notes in reverse order under `* MEETINGS`, and I'd like to refile the new meeting notes to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7kt7nh/is_it_possible_to_refile_an_orgmode_header_in/

To recap, use `(setq org-reverse-note-order t)` to revert the new notes order when refiling. Documentation for [`org-rev-note-order`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-Copy.html):

```
Non-nil means store new notes at the beginning of a file or entry.

When nil, new notes will be filed to the end of a file or entry.
This can also be a list with cons cells of regular expressions that
are matched against file names, and values.
```